# How can I run this command using wand-py and imagemagick

Tags: python, imagemagick-convert, wand

I'm attempting to recreate the following command using wand-py and imagemagick:

```
convert -density 500 hello_world.pdf -quality 100 -monochrome -enhance – morphology close diamond hello_world.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to bind methods from MagickCore, and MagickWand libraries. Keep in mind that Kernel performance can differ widely between systems, so don't be surprised if you hit a `Operation canceled' message when working with large density images.

```py
import ctypes
from wand.api import libmagick, library
from wand.image import Image

"""
Kernel info methods on MagickCore library.
"""
libmagick.AcquireKernelInfo.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p,)
libmagick.AcquireKernelInfo.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
libmagick.DestroyKernelInfo.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)
libmagick.DestroyKernelInfo.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

"""
Morphology method on MagickWand library.
"""
library.MagickMorphologyImage.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,  # wand
                                          ctypes.c_int,     # method
                                          ctypes.c_long,    # iterations
                                          ctypes.c_void_p)  # kernel
"""
Enhance method on MagickWand library.
"""
library.MagickEnhanceImage.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,)    # wand

# convert -density 500 hello_world.pdf
with Image(filename='pdf-sample.pdf', resolution=500) as img:
    # -quality 100
    img.compression_quality = 100
    # -monochrome
    img.quantize(2,       # Target colors
                 'gray',  # Colorspace
                 1,       # Treedepth
                 False,   # No Dither
                 False)   # Quantization error
    # -enhance
    library.MagickEnhanceImage(img.wand)
    # -morphology close diamond
    p = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'Diamond')
    kernel = libmagick.AcquireKernelInfo(p)
    CloseMorphology = 9  # See `morphology.h'
    library.MagickMorphologyImage(img.wand, CloseMorphology, 1, kernel)
    kernel = libmagick.DestroyKernelInfo(kernel) # Free memory
    # hello_world.jpg
    img.save(filename='hello_world.jpg')
```

Comment: thanks for the code! I'm receiving `ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type` error on this line:  `kernel = libmagick.AcquireKernelInfo('Diamond')`, I'm using version ImageMagick-6.9.8-Q8 and Wand 0.4.4 if that helps.

Comment: Hmm. Try using `create_string_buffer`. I'll updated example

Comment: Similar error: `TypeError: Diamond`, from this module `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in create_string_buffer(init, size)` at this line `p = ctypes.create_string_buffer('Diamond')`. Again I appreciate the help!

Comment: Ah. Might be related to Python version. Try adding prefixing the python string a bytes. `b'Diamond'`. Double check the docs with your version of python [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) (last block of examples). Good luck!

Comment: Yes I was using Python 3, should have put that in the first message. The `b'Diamond` worked perfectly. Your original  code suggestion worked as well. Thank you so much!